dotnet run tests inside Solution Folder
I have two solution folders

Tests - Tests simple Unit Tests
Integration Tests - Tests running again the backend

Is there a way to run Tests inside a Solution Folder for example:
Only inside Tests Folder
Only inside Integration Folder
I already found this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/705 (quite old and not really what I want)
One Way I think about is using Conitional set of IsTestProject but how can I do this in a simple way

Not sure if I misunderstood you post but you can specify a path to the test project file when you run dotnet test.  You can also create additional solutions and only include the test projects you want executed for each solution file.

Sounds like an interesting solution, that should be doing what I want, but is there a possibility to run all Integration Tests inside a SolutionFolder, you know the virtual folders that the IDE represents inside a solution

Another Problem could be that I would need to build the solution one time for running each Solution

You can target a solution file or a single test project file.  For each scenario of a combination of test projects you want to run, create a solution file and include those projects.  There's a --no-build flag that will avoid rebuilding projects when you run dotnet test so you can build your all-encompassing solution then target the test-combo solutions running tests alone and there won't be any unnecessary rebuilds.
If you want to capture solutions/projects in a directory or directory tree to run, write a PowerShell script to discover and run the test projects/solutions.

I think I will try it for the pipe
